# C/C++ Windows or Linux map random memory blocks into consecutive order

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, memory-management

My requirement is to emulate an old motorola memory controller.

Basically the controller maps 8 x 8Kbyte memory blocks into a 64Kbyte address space for subsequent access by a CPU.  The controller has access to upto 1024 such 8K blocks.

At the moment I have accomplished this by using a large flat array like so:

```
unsigned char Memory[1024][8192];
int MappedMemoryBank[8];
short int Address;
```

Then to access any particular memory address I use something like this

```
unsigned char aByte = Memory[MappedMemoryBank[Address>>13]][Address&0x1FFF];
```

This works fine but as memory references comprise 99% of processing time it is very inefficient.

Is there a memory mapping mechanism where I can allocate a number (1024) of memory blocks and then map them (in any order) into a consecutive memory space?

This would reduce my memory references to:

```
unsigned char *Memory;
Memory = pointed to first byte of (re-)mapped memory

unsigned char aByte = Memory[Address];
```

Which would be an order of magnitude faster (I hope)

A solution for either Windows and/or Linux is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find in Linux there is the mremap() function.

And in Windows is the AWE Address Windowing Exextensions MapUserPhysicalPages function allows this.

I just tested the AWE functions and they work well.  Not sure how efficient they are but they work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

How often do you change the mapping vs. how often you access the memory?

Assuming accessing it is a lot more common than rearranging it, I'd probably keep two copies of the data: a "mapped" array, and a "physical array".

Your use "ping-pongs" between the two. That is, when you create a mapping, you copy the data in the correct order from the physical to the mapped array. When you need to rearrange it, copy back to the physical array, and then (again, in the correct order) to the mapped array.

This is likely to slow re-mapping by a factor of 10 (or something on that order) but speed up accesses by at least a factor of 10 as well. Since the re-mapping apparently took less than 1% of the time previously, that should be a fairly substantial win.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  That would surely work but a better answer is included in this post.